# DataTemplate vs ItemContainerTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is ItemContainerTemplate used for? It is derived from DataTemplate, but I don't see any difference between them except the ItemContainerTemplateKey property. When should I use one and when the other?

Answer (score 9):

The only difference between `DataTemplate` and `ItemContainerTemplate` is the way the resource dictionary key is automatically provided (assuming it is not set explicitly). Namely, `DataTemplate` is decorated with `[DictionaryKeyProperty("DataTemplateKey")]` attribute, and the `DataTemplateKey` is basically defined as:

```
public object DataTemplateKey
{
    get { return (DataType != null) ? new DataTemplateKey(DataType) : null; 
}
```

See [DataTemplate source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/DataTemplate.cs,76ba2add9ef6ea65) for reference.

`ItemContainerTemplate` derives from `DataTemplate`, but is decorated with `[DictionaryKeyProperty("ItemContainerTemplateKey")]` attribute (which in practice replaces the inherited one), and `ItemContainerTemplateKey` property is defined as follows:

```
public object ItemContainerTemplateKey
{
    get { return (DataType != null) ? new ItemContainerTemplateKey(DataType) : null; }
}
```

See [ItemContainerTemplate source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemContainerTemplate.cs,6b0d328ba42bcb82) for reference.

The difference seems small - `DataTemplate` returns an instance of `DataTemplateKey` and `ItemContainerTemplate` returns an instance of `ItemContainerTemplateKey` (both derive from `TemplateKey`). So basically these two are equivalent<sup>*1*</sup>:

```
<ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" />
<DataTemplate x:Key="{ItemContainerTemplateKey {x:Type sys:String}}" />
```

and so are these:

```
<ItemContainerTemplate x:Key="{DataTemplateKey {x:Type sys:String}}" />
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" />
```

The **main** practical difference between these two is that `DataTemplate` with default key is treated as an *implicit template*<sup>*2*</sup>, whereas `ItemContainerTemplate` is not. In fact, you need to manually reference it, e.g.:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource {ItemContainerTemplate {x:Type sys:String}}}" />
```

I'm not sure about the intentions behind creating `ItemContainerTemplate` class. I guess it gives you a clearer overview of the code, where you know that such a template is specifically intended to be used in an `ItemsControl` (or a derived control). Also, I guess it would prove to be pretty simple to write a strongly reusable `DataTemplateSelector` that would take advantage of this class.

---

<sup>*1*</sup> *They're not equivalent in the sense that created objects are of different types, but functionally they're equivalent.*

<sup>*2*</sup> *Implicit templates are applied to all objects of corresponding type within the scope, unless a template is set explicitly.*

Answer (score 2):

The ItemContainerTemplate describes the world around your Item. For example in a ListBox the selection rectangle around your ListBoxItem. The DataTemplate describes how you ListBoxItem apears and of which elements it consists.

Dr. WPF did a good example:
http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/

Comment: I think you've mistaken `ItemContainerTemplate` class for `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` property...

Comment: Depends what you want. If you do not want to have the typical ItemConainer for your item generated you can also change this. Typically the style should be enough in many cases... sorry for the misleading information with the example by Dr.WPF

Answer (score 1):

You can put an `ItemContainerTemplate` in a `ResourceDictionary`, and it will automatically use the `DataType` as its key.

That's the [only difference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemContainerTemplate.cs).

Comment: Actually, it will use `new ItemContainerTemplateKey(DataType)` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

ItemContainerTemplate is useful/necessary when you need different Item containers for an ItemsControl.
Usually the XAML infracstructure decides which item container is used for a given ItemsControl:

- ListBox uses ListBoxItem
- DataGrid uses DataRow
- ComboBox uses ComboBoxItem
- Menu uses MenuItem

As for a Menu you would sometimes want a Separator (which is not a MenuItem technically)
That's where ItemContainerTemplate, ItemContainerTemplateSelector and ItemContainerTemplatekey come into play.
Based on the viewmodel/datacontext type or one/many of its property values you can switch between a Separator in an ItemContainerTemplate and a MenuItem in another
ItemContainerTemplate.
You may use triggers or a ItemContainerTemplateSelector to achieve this.

Actually and honestly I am myself just now about to understand what the ItemContainerTemplateKey is for.
I think to have understood that it's an easy way to map an ItemContainerTemplate to a data type without the need for a Selector or code behind or triggers.

If you're fine with the default ItemContainerTemplate you simply don't need to deal with it in your XAML. Manipulating the ItemsContainer style can be achieved within the ItemContainerTemplate. Having a custom DataTemplate to bind your data (and also to style it) is done within the ItemTemplate.
Usage of ItemContainerTemplate is rarely needed. But sometimes very handy.

Answer (score -1):

You could check that Link to see the difference between controltemplate and datatemplate and hierarchicaldatatemplate itemspaneltemplate:

http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/controltemplate-vs-datatemplate-vs-hierarchicaldatatemplate-vs-itemspaneltemplate/

Comment: Or you could just copy the relevant parts here instead of redirecting users offsite. Links can break you know...

Comment: The article referred to does not mention ItemContainerTemplate, which was the original poster's question.