# WPF: Two way binding does not set source

Tags: c#, wpf

My two way binding is just working from the source to the TextBox - I can see the default value in the TextBox and even the new value when I change it from the code-behind, but when I change the Text in the TextBox the value doesn't get updated in the Model, even after the TextBox loses focus. The DataContext is also set.

Version.Set doesn't even get called - tested by setting a breakpoint.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Issues}">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestReport.Version, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Models:

```
public class TestIssue
{
    public JiraIssue Issue { get; set; }
    public TestReport TestReport { get; set; }
}

public class TestReport : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string version = "Defalut Value";

    public string Version
    {
        get => this.version;
        set
        {
            if (value == this.version) return;
            this.version = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestIssue> Issues { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TestIssue>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Explicitly setting the UpdateSourceTrigger works, even setting it to FocusLost, which confuses me even more.

Comment: Typically data context is set after initializing components.

Comment: @Sinatr Still no luck with that.

Comment: The question lacks details and there are many errors in the code. See [mcve]. I doubt anyone will be able to help you without it.

Answer (score 2):

First, your XAML code is incorrect and it should be like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestReport.Version, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

You cannot place `<TextBox/>` element inside `<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>` directlyand it should be placed inside `<ItemContainerTemplate >`.
To update the `TextBox` you need to tell `TextBox` element when it should update its value when the source changes by adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding script as shown in the above code.

Comment: Why not just a DataTemplate instead of ItemContainerTemplate?

Comment: You can use DataTemplate as well. To get more details, you may read [DataTemplate vs ItemContainerTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824607/datatemplate-vs-itemcontainertemplate). @Clemens

Comment: That's what I did, and also [How to: Add Row Details to a DataGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-add-row-details-to-a-datagrid-control) where they use the far more common DataTemplate. Can't see any particular reason for ItemContainerTemplate.